# Batch delete selected items on ListView/GridView

Tags: android, listview, gridview, batch-processing

Following the guide found here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB I went up to a dead end on how to remove all the selected items from the `listView`'s adapter.

In the guide it is shown as a method called `deleteSelectedItems();` but since it is never implemented, I got stuck. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I asume you are using a List. Do the following:

```
private void deleteSelectedItems() {
   SparseBooleanArray checked = mListView.getCheckedItemPositions();+
   List<YourObject> list = mListOfObjects;
   for (int i = 0; i < mListView.getCount(); i++)
        if (checked.get(i)) 
            YourObject item = list.get(i);
            mListOfObjects.remove(item); //or whatever you want to do with it.
}
```

Comment: Your algorithm is close but is slightly off. Removing an item changes the positions of any items after it. So, you need to sort the list of positions and remove them from the bottom up. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/ActionMode/ActionModeMC/src/com/commonsware/android/actionmodemc/ActionModeDemo.java

Comment: @CommonsWare you are totally right. I'm going to fix it.

Comment: Yeah, that is the reason that drove me to ask a question in here. @CommonsWare link solved the issue